# seperating rent payments by month in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not gonna lie, this is for a hw assignment, and I can't figure this part out.

From this query so far, I can get all of the rent revenue from each apartment complex. I just need to be able to separate it by month.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT cmplxName AS 'Complex Name', rentTrandate AS 'month' , sum(rentPaid) AS 'Rent Revenue'
FROM complex
INNER JOIN apartment
ON complex.cmplxID = apartment.cmplxID 
INNER JOIN lease
ON apartment.aptNumber = lease.aptNumber and apartment.cmplxID = lease.cmplxID
INNER JOIN rent
ON lease.leaseID = rent.leaseID
GROUP BY cmplxName
```

this is how the data is supposed to look:

```
complexName     month   rentRevenue
Fox Run         March   1250.00
Oak Meadows     March   1500.00
Oak Meadows     April   700.00
Villa Maria     March   1200.00
Villa Maria     April   600.00
```

This is how my data looks now:

```
Fox Run     2015-03-01  1250.00
Oak Meadows 2015-03-01  2200.00
Villa Maria 2015-03-01  1800.00
```

I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the definition of your month field, and change the grouping to group by it as well as the complex name:

```
SELECT cmplxName AS 'Complex Name', MONTHNAME(rentTrandate) AS 'month' , sum(rentPaid) AS 'Rent Revenue'
FROM complex
INNER JOIN apartment
ON complex.cmplxID = apartment.cmplxID 
INNER JOIN lease
ON apartment.aptNumber = lease.aptNumber and apartment.cmplxID = lease.cmplxID
INNER JOIN rent
ON lease.leaseID = rent.leaseID
GROUP BY cmplxName, month
```

Answer (score 0):

hi keelsinith This will be done as following 
use this SELECT DATENAME(month,rentTrandate) 
DATENAME is an SQL method demanding 2 argument DATETIME(interval,YourDateValue)
interval takes  year,dayofweek,month

```
SELECT cmplxName AS 'Complex Name', SELECT DATENAME(month,rentTrandate) AS 'month' , sum(rentPaid) AS 'Rent Revenue'
```

FROM complex
INNER JOIN apartment
ON complex.cmplxID = apartment.cmplxID 
INNER JOIN lease
ON apartment.aptNumber = lease.aptNumber and apartment.cmplxID = lease.cmplxID
INNER JOIN rent
ON lease.leaseID = rent.leaseID
GROUP BY cmplxName

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you include both the year and the month.  Also, table aliases and qualified column names are highly recommended:

```
SELECT c.mplxName as Complex_Name, year(r.rentTrandate) as yyyy,
       month(r.rentTrandate) as mm, sum(rentPaid) as Rent_Revenue
FROM complex c INNER JOIN
     apartment a
     ON c.cmplxID = a.cmplxID INNER JOIN
     lease l
     ON a.aptNumber = l.aptNumber and a.cmplxID = l.cmplxID INNER JOIN
     rent r
     ON l.leaseID = r.leaseID
GROUP BY c.cmplxName, year(r.rentTrandate), month(r.rentTrandate)
ORDER BY c.cmplxName, year(r.rentTrandate), month(r.rentTrandate);
```

This gives the month as a number, but that is more appropriate for sorting the result set anyway.